# Rails is not creating hidden field for put method on an update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have a REST resource called Greetings.

Here is my routes file:

```
resources :greetings
```

I have a form to create or update a greeting as follows:

```
     <%= form_tag(@greeting, :remote => true, :id => 'greeting_form') do %>
    <%= text_area :greeting, :content, :rows => 3, :placeholder => "Type your message..." %>
    <% end %>
```

note: I am using form_tag because this form also collects user data.

This is supposed to create a hidden field with method=> put but its not so it can't find the route.

Any ideas how I can get this to submit to the update action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```
<%= form_tag(@greeting, :remote => true, :id => 'greeting_form', :method => :put) do %>
```

and everything should be working.

Comment: Thanks ream88. That is what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form_for` tag and still collect user data like this:

```
  <%= form_for @greeting, :validate => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3, :placeholder => "Type your message..." %>
    <%= f.fields_for @user do |u| %>
      <%= u.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end
```

Comment: Thank you Arun. I would like to try out your answer after. I am sure its the way I should be doing it.